# How to redirect from controller to view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

It was really hard to formulate the title of this question. I`ll start with a code snippet:

```
[..]
<a href="#" id="register-link">register</a>
[..]
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#register-link').on('click',function(){
        $.get(baseurl + 'index.php/auth/register', function(response){
            $('#popup-div').html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

controller method auth/register ends with:

```
$this->load->view('auth/register_form', $data);
```

The basic idea is that when user clicks on "register" in menu a popup show up instead of loading a new page. Registration works.

However, there are two ways how auth/register method can end:

```
function register()
    {
        // a bunch of $this->form_validation->set_rules();
        // and other server side logic
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {    
        // server side logic
            redirect('auth');
        } else{
        //getting same $data
            $this->load->view('auth/register_form', $data)
        }
    }
```

So the problem is that if I get validation errors (form validation doesn`t run and I get html response) a new page loads with form showing errors instead of doing that in the popup. If registration is successful I get new page reload just to display to user that registration was successfull which is annoying. So I want to check if controller redirects and to pass that redirect url into the same div.

I looked up same similar questions but can not get it working. So far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#register-link').on('click',function(){
        $.get(baseurl + 'index.php/auth/register', function(response){
            if (response.redirect) {
                //alert(response.redirect);
                $.get(response.redirect, function(response2){
                    $('#popup-div').html(response2);                    
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#popup-div').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

but nothing changes and I do not get any errors. If I understand the problem correctly then call is made just once so I will always get the view. I tried to remove  `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` part but still nothing. If I will try to attach ajax call to every "submit" I (think) will mess up the validations.

**UPDATE:**
From comments below I got that it could be easier to work inside tank auth controller. First I`ll show full sequence how Tank auth redirects. Inside auth/register it is actually

```
$this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_registration_completed_1'));
```

where:

```
function _show_message($message)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/auth/');
    }
```

and:

```
function index()
    {
        if ($message = $this->session->flashdata('message')) {
            $this->load->view('auth/general_message', array('message' => $message));
        } else {
            redirect('/auth/login/');
        }
    }
```

The idea behind it is that _show_message is called in 17 different situation with different message to display. I want to handle all of those situation within my popup div. I tried to change:

```
$this->_show_message_JSON($this->lang->line('auth_message_registration_completed_1'));
```

where:

```
function _show_message_JSON($message)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        $data['redirect'] = '1';
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

and handle logic in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#register-link').on('click',function(){
        $.get(baseurl + 'index.php/auth/register', function(response){
            if(typeof response == 'object'){
                //alert(response);
                $.get(baseurl + 'index.php/auth', function(response2){
                    $('#popup-div').html(response2);                    
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#popup-div').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However what I get if validation is ok is:

```
{"redirect":"1"}
<form action="http://localhost/test4/index.php/auth/register" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<table>
        <tr>
        <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" value="user21" id="username" maxlength="20" size="30"  />
</td>
        <td style="color: red;"></td>
    </tr>
[...]
```

which is basically the source code except with attached first line.

Comment: I think you need to rethink how you want to let this flow. You can use the json datatype to make things easier and just send a response depending on what happend and let the browser handle things from there depending on the response you got. Why do you have to redirect? Can't you maybe do the authentication inside a model and call the function that way?

Comment: I would chose to use JSON and handle the logic in JS if I would make contoller from scratch. But I am using Tank auth library for registration and it uses a lot of redirects. It just seem easyer to handle redirect response rather then to change whole library

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I have never used that before I don't think I can help you. Goodluck

Comment: Your best bet is to create a class that extends Auth and overload the `register` function. It should always `echo` something back. (Which loading a view does.) Instead of redirects, send back a json object with some kind of state reporting var. Have the `success` function respond accordingly. You will likely want to return the html of the view thru the json object instead of simply using `$this->load->view`.

Comment: I am not sure how to overload register and how to return html thru JSON but I tried some changes and updated the question