# How to use CodeIgniters form validation in dynamically built html element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have the problem discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324576/how-to-redirect-from-controller-to-view-in-codeigniter) but I realized that I need to tackle one problem by one and this one has to be first. I will use a bit easyer example with Contact Us form.

I have a controller:

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            [...]
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full name', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Your email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('msg', 'Message', 'trim|required');

            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('contact', $data);
            } 
            else
            {
                // Configure email library
                [...]
                $this->email->send();

                $this->load->view('contact_success');
            }

        }
```

and view:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php echo form_open('contact'); ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Full name</label></br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" value="<?php echo set_value('name') ?>" ></br>
                <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label></br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" value="<?php echo set_value('email') ?>"></br>
                <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label></br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="subject" value="<?php echo set_value('subject') ?>"></br>
                <?php echo form_error('subject'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="msg">Message</label></br>
                <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Enter your message"><?php echo set_value('msg') ?></textarea></br>
                <?php echo form_error('msg'); ?>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="send" />

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I call the controller using url I get nicely working contact us form. However I find it annoying that such a small thing as Contact Us has to be loaded in new page. So I have this jquery in my main page view:

```
[..]
<a href="#" id="contact-link">register</a>
[..]
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-link').on('click',function(){
        $.get(baseurl + 'index.php/contact', function(response){
            $('#popup-div').html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

So now I have "embed" the contact us controller in my main view. However I displays form and actually send email when the form validation run. But if form validation doesn`t run a new page is loaded displaying same form with validation error. I want validation error displayed in my popup div.

I have seen this done in a lot of websites but can not get my head around on how to do it with CI. Do I have to call contact controller after every submit? I think the problem is that $.get is called just once so callback handles response only once. I tried to remove `$('#contact-link').on('click',function(){` part but i doesn`t help. I even though about putting $.get inside a function and making it recursive but I am afraid that it would mess up form validation.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is jquery validation, and to send the contact data using ajax.

Here is how you can do it : 
In your main view, have a hidden div or a hidden bootstrap modal that contains the contact form, when the user clicks that link the modal shows up with the contact form.
From here you need a jquery validation plugin that checks the user inputs when clicking on submit, if the user inputs are filled correctly, send an ajax request to a method inside the contact controller which runs the form_validation method, if the form is successful submitted, send the email, and return a response saying contact successful.
Then if the contact was made successfully, then close the modal, and show a notification saying contact successfully made.

Your **contact controller** will look something like this :

```
public function check_contact()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Your email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('msg', 'Message', 'trim|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $response = "KO";
            echo $response;
        } 
        else
        {
            // Configure email library
            $this->email->send();
            $response = "OK"
            echo $response;
        }

    }
```

And your **jquery ajax** would look something like this :

```
//Fetch the contact form using id="ContactForm"
var form = $('#ContactForm')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here/check_contact',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success : function(data){
    if (data == "KO") 
      { 
        $('#ErrorDiv').html("There was an error subbmiting your contact").show();
      }
    if (data == "OK") 
      { 
        $('#ContactModal').hide();
        $('#SuccessDiv').delay(800).fadeIn();
      }
    }
});
```

Jquery Validation Plugin : https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: This looks like a great way to deal the problem. I tried to look into Validation plugin but did not get exactly how it works. My conserns are about implementing it together with CI validations. If I got it right then I can still set rules in CI controller? But how to ensure that CI form_error and set_value will continue to work? Does jQuery plugin will undestand that or I should echo all information and then write some JS logic?

Comment: When using jQuery validation plugin, it validates the user input when clicking on submit, and outputs errors on a label right below the input where it has errors, see this jsfiddle for a quick and useful demo :

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oohd8u22/ And for the CI form validation, it will still run even if we validates the inputs using Validation plugin, as shown in the controller that i wrote for you, it will check the user inputs even if already validated, and it will return a response of KO if any input has an error, or an OK response if the validation was successfully ran. If you wish to customize the validation plugin errors, use : form .error {custom css rules here} for changing the way the error looks

Comment: Just to confirm that I understood the code snipet you gave in answer - I can actually leave it as in your example without specifying validation rules in client side(jQuery plugin)?  Fetching form + ajax handles that controller gets values to validate? But if my only response from server is echo-ing response statuss will CI validation could still display errors(form_error)?

Comment: Ok, it work but only if I remove all the CI validation function from main view form (set_value and form_error). If I leave them then my main view controller doesn`t recognize them. And thats problem because while CI validation does validate it does not return any information about errors which is bad for user experience. I could of course do client side validation with jquery but thats bad because it is possible to temper with js and hack validation. So what I am up for is a way to call controller from my main view and repeatedly check response in ajax after every submit.

Comment: dude why do you put your validation on the main view, it has to be on the contact controller, then the jquery calls the method on the contact controller to check if the form is filled correctly, if filled correctly it will say so, if not, you can't echo the form errors using jquery unless you do manual validation (regex and input lenght) then return specific errors concerning every single input.

Comment: Also the codeigniter form validation is not that secure as you think, all inputs has to be sanitized before using them, use xss filter, and common php sanitizing methods (trim strip tags etc)

Answer (score 0):

As I think that this is really nice way to create good user interface I will answer my own question for others to use.

The problem is that my JS requests controller on clicking contact-link but never handles the submit.

I left that as it was but added another JS:

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var formData = $(this).serialize(); 
    var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action'); 
    $.post(actionUrl, formData, function(response){ 
        $('#popup-div').html(response);
    });
});
```

and in my view I changed:

```
<?php echo form_open('contact', array('id'=>'contact-form')); ?>
```

Without `event.preventDefault();` the controller would validate and continue flow until a `load->view` is called and that view is opened in in new page.